# convert HttpHeader to Map

Tags: http, http-headers, dart

When using dart on the browser (no dart:io) is there a ready to use way, to convert the string returned by `req.getAllResponseHeaders()`, where req is a `HttpRequest`, into a dart Map. I was a bit surprised by the fact that there is no ready method here, since all http related functions seem to use the headers in a Map format.

Also if there really are no ready methods, how would you approach converting a header returned by the `.getAllResponseHeaders()`?

```
date: Mon, 25 May 2015 06:03:29 GMT
x-content-type-options: nosniff
server: dart:io with Shelf
authorization: ShelfAuthJwtSession eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzI1MzM4MDgsImV4cCI6MTQzMjUzNTYwOCwiaXNzIjoic3VwZXIgYXBwIiwic3ViIjoiZnJlZCIsImF1ZCI6W251bGxdLCJzaWQiOiJjM2E0Y2IzMC1lY2EwLTExZTQtZmNiYS0xM2YwNjgwYTQxMDQiLCJ0c2UiOjE0MzI2MjAyMDh9.AB0TCJPcioCtBA-qzO1QSLuH7HUxHCbDZTUVANp5Dbo
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Authorization
access-control-allow-credentials: true
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

into a map.

Comment: I'm starting to think the best way is to create a regexp matching all keys and one matching all values. Then create the map out of two lists.

Comment: This regexp takes the keys `/.+?(?=\: )/g` excluding the ": " For some reason the same thing does not work for the values `/(?=\: ).*/g` does anybody know why?

Comment: This method is marked `unstable` so you probably shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getAllResponseHeaders()` is unstable so you shouldn't rely on it/shouldn't be using it.

If you need a Map format you can use the [`responseHeaders`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HttpRequest#id_responseHeaders) getter from `HttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

response.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap();